# null userId, Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart

I have an issue with userId in Habits table. it is a foreign key from id in Users Table. but I keep getting the error "Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value " from AddHabitDialogController class.
obviously userId should never be null. where is the issue? how can I solve it?
if more code is needed you can check : https://github.com/sarasoltan/habit_tracker

Users Table:

```
class UsersTable {
  static const String tableName = 'Users';

  static const String id = 'id';
  static const String email = 'email';
  

  static const String createQuery = '''
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tableName (
    $id integer primary key autoincrement,
    $email text not null unique);''';

  @override
  String toString() => 'Person, ID: $id, email: $email';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant Users other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

Habits table:

```
    class HabitsTable {
  static const String tableName = 'Habits';

  static const String id = 'id';
  static const String userId = 'userId';
  static const String text = 'text';
  static const String emoji = 'emoji';
  static const String period = 'period';
  static const String startPeriod = 'startPeriod';

  static const String createQuery = '''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tableName (
      $id integer primary key autoincrement,
      $userId integer not null,
      $text text not null,
      $emoji text not null,
      $period text not null,
      $startPeriod integer,
      FOREIGN Key($userId) REFERENCES ${UsersTable.tableName}(${UsersTable.id}));''';
```

User model class:

```
class Users {
  late final int id;
  late String email;

  Users({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
  });

  Users.fromDb(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map[UsersTable.id];
    email = map[UsersTable.email];
  }
}
```

Habit model class:

```
    class Habit {
  late final int id;
  late final int userId;
  late String text;
  late String emoji;
  late final List<int> period;
  late final DateTime? startPeriod;

  Habit(
      {
      //required this.id,
      required this.userId,
      required this.text,
      required this.emoji,
      required this.period,
      this.startPeriod});

  Habit.fromDb(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map[HabitsTable.id] as int;
    userId = map[HabitsTable.userId] as int;
    text = map[HabitsTable.text] as String;
    emoji = map[HabitsTable.emoji];
    period = (jsonDecode(map[HabitsTable.period]) as List<dynamic>)
        .map((e) => e as int)
        .toList();
    if (map[HabitsTable.startPeriod] != null) {
      startPeriod =
          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map[HabitsTable.startPeriod]);
    } else {
      startPeriod = null;
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toDb() {
    Users? owner;
    return {
      //HabitsTable.id: id,
      HabitsTable.userId: owner!.id,
      HabitsTable.text: text,
      HabitsTable.emoji: emoji,
      HabitsTable.period: jsonEncode(period),
      HabitsTable.startPeriod: startPeriod?.millisecondsSinceEpoch
    };
  }
```

AddHabitDialogController(error):

```
    class AddHabitDialogController {
  Users? owner;
  //final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  //String get owneruserId => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.id;

  final List<bool> period = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true];
  int? id;
  int? userId;
  String? emoji;
  String? text;
  StartPeriod startPeriod = StartPeriod.none;

  final StreamController<bool> _addBtnEnabledCtrl = StreamController();
  Stream<bool> get addBtnEnabled => _addBtnEnabledCtrl.stream;

  final StreamController<StartPeriod> _selectedStartPeriodCtrl =
      StreamController();
  Stream<StartPeriod> get selectedStartPeriod =>
      _selectedStartPeriodCtrl.stream;

  final StreamController<bool> _loadingCtrl = StreamController();
  Stream<bool> get loading => _loadingCtrl.stream;

  void changePeriodValue(int index, bool newValue) {
    period[index] = newValue;
    _updateAddBtnEnabledState();
  }

  void changeTextValue(String newValue) {
    text = newValue;
    _updateAddBtnEnabledState();
  }

  void changeEmojiValue(String newEmoji) {
    emoji = newEmoji;
    _updateAddBtnEnabledState();
  }

  void changeStartPeriod(StartPeriod newValue) {
    startPeriod = newValue;
    _selectedStartPeriodCtrl.add(startPeriod);
  }

  Future<void> addHabit(BuildContext context) async {
    _loadingCtrl.add(true);
    final dataService = GetIt.I.get<DataService>();

    final List<int> forPeriod = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < period.length; i++) {
      if (period[i]) {
        forPeriod.add(i + 1);
      }
    }

    final habit = Habit(
        //id: id!,
        userId: owner!.id, //error from here
        emoji: emoji!,
        text: text!,
        period: forPeriod,
        startPeriod: _calculateStartPeriodDateTime());
    await dataService.addHabit(habit);
    _loadingCtrl.add(false);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _updateAddBtnEnabledState() {
    _addBtnEnabledCtrl.add((text?.isNotEmpty ?? false) &&
        (emoji?.isNotEmpty ?? false) &&
        period.where((e) => e).isNotEmpty);
  }

  DateTime? _calculateStartPeriodDateTime() {
    final now = DateTime.now();

    switch (startPeriod) {
      case StartPeriod.today:
        return DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
      case StartPeriod.thisMonth:
        return DateTime(now.year, now.month);
      case StartPeriod.thisYear:
        return DateTime(now.year);
      case StartPeriod.none:
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    _addBtnEnabledCtrl.close();
    _loadingCtrl.close();
    _selectedStartPeriodCtrl.close();
  }
}

enum StartPeriod { none, today, thisMonth, thisYear }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the local variable of AddHabitDialogController **owner** can't be referenced before it is declared

```
class AddHabitDialogController {
  Users? owner; // -> you did not assign this owner?
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. yes but I keep getting errors. Can you please help me doing it?

Comment: I changed the code: `final UserService userService = UserService();

String get owneremail => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.email;
  final owner = userService.getUser(email: owneremail);` I need to use await but it does not let me do it. what should I do?